# References for soft constraints definition

Tags: optimization, references

I am looking for some reference that defines or presents in a clear way the concept of "soft constraints".

The context:

I writing an article. For a particular problem, I propose a solution including some soft constraints, and call it "soft HLPC". Here, I am using the term "soft constraint" in the sense that is a set of conditions that the violation causes a "penalty" in the target value (in the likelihood, in my case).

Now, I need to explain the used term. For this, I wrote that I am using the word "soft" in reference to the "soft constraints" concept, but I lacking a good reference to define such concept.

I found several definitions in the web (as in [Here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/soft-constraints-and-hard-constraints), [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_(mathematics)#Hard_and_soft_constraints) and [here](https://help.palisade.com/v8/en/@RISK/4-Tools/1-Optimize/Soft-Constraints-Penalty-Functions.htm)) that are good to explain the concept, but it is not suitable for use as a reference in a paper.

Can anyone provide a good reference (article or book) that defines/explains the concept of soft constraint for citing?